# Extjs4 listener for window

Tags: extjs4

In my application i have many windows and panels and im using custom scrollbars. So for each window or panel i need to specify afterlayout listener to get the custom scroll bar

```
            listeners:{
    afterlayout: function(c){
    fleXenv.fleXcrollMain(c.body.id);
      }
    }
```

So what im looking for is i need to add this listener globally for windows and panels so that by adding this code one time should effect on all windows or panels.

Is there any way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your custom scrollbar is used in all Windows and Panels of your application. Hence there is nothing wrong with extending the core ExtJs classes IMHO. 
Implement it as a 'feature' that is enabled by default but - for the rare cases where you don't want the scrollbar - can be disabled.

```
Ext.define('patch.Ext.panel.Panel-scrollbar', {
    override: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

    enableCustomScrollbar: true,

    afterLayout: function() {
        this.fixScrollbar();
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },

    fixScrollbar: function() {
        if(this.enableCustomScrollbar) {
            // your code
        }
    }
});
```

Load with `Ext.require('patch.Ext.panel.Panel-scrollbar')` or add it as dependency (`requires`) to your application definition.

`Ext.window.Window` extends from `Ext.panel.Panel`, hence it will inherit the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own panel and window extending ExtJS default components. You can define desired listener, set up xtypes and then use these modified components in your application.

Another solution would be to override existing Ext.panel.Panel and Ext.window.Window with [Ext.override](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext-method-override)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, I think the best way to do this is to define your personal Window/Panel class. Yes, one way is to use Ext.override function but I don't think it's a good idea.

I suggest you to do this:

```
Ext.define ('MyCustomWindow', {
  extend: 'Ext.window.Window' ,
  listeners: {
    afterlayout: function (win) {
      fleXenv.fleXcrollMain (win.body.id);
    }
  }
}

Ext.define ('MyCustomPanel', {
  extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel' ,
  listeners: {
    afterlayout: function (panel) {
      fleXenv.fleXcrollMain (panel.body.id);
    }
  }
}
```

Now, you can instantiate MyCustomWindow and MyCustomPanel, leaving Ext.window.Window and Ext.panel.Panel unchanged.

Another way is to use WindowManager and PanelManager (this one defined by yourself):

```
Ext.WindowManager.register (window1);
Ext.WindowManager.register (window2);
Ext.WindowManager.register (window3);

Ext.WindowManager.each (function (win) {
  win.on ('afterlayout', function (window) {
    fleXenv.fleXcrollMain (window.body.id);
  });
});
```

In this case, first you have to instantiate your windows and panels, register them to their managers and then invoke the each function as I did in the example above.